# Using Objects in chartjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

the issue I have now is that I'm trying to use objects in the "data" field of my Chartjs script. This is my code below:

```js
<canvas id="QGL_Chart"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>

<script>
var interval = window.onload = () => { 
 var selectedDate;   
const buyPriceData = [];
const buyVolData = [];

const sellPriceData = [];
const sellVolData = [];


    var ctx = document.getElementById("QGL_Chart").getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 934;
ctx.canvas.height = 400;

         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Line A',
    
        data: [{
          x: 90,
          y: 90
        }, {
          x: 20,
          y: 96
       
        }, {
          x: 15,
          y: 97
      
        }]
      },
      {
        label: 'Line B',
    
        data: [{
          x: 10,
          y: 96
         
        }, {
          x: 20,
          y: 95.8
        
        }, {
          x: 100,
          y: 99
          
        }]
      }
      ]
  },
    
 
       options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Equilibrum Graph',
      fontSize: 18
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "bottom"
    },
    scales: {
     xAxes: [{
              
              ticks: {
      reverse: false,
     // stepSize: 6,
      min: 0
    }
    }]
  }
  }
  });
  
function refreshCurveData () {
 selectedDate = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass .column-date.sorting_1")[1].textContent;
buyPriceTable = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass td.column-price");
buyVolTable = document.querySelectorAll(".buyclass td.column-volume");

sellPriceTable = document.querySelectorAll(".sellclass td.column-price");
sellVolTable = document.querySelectorAll(".sellclass td.column-volume");

let i = 0;
do {
var  buyPriceData1 = buyPriceTable[i].textContent;
 var buyVolData1 = buyVolTable[i].textContent;

var sellPriceData1 = sellPriceTable[i].textContent;
var sellVolData1 = sellVolTable[i].textContent;
buyPriceData[i] = `{x: ${buyPriceData1}, y: ${buyVolData1}}`
sellPriceData[i] = `{x: ${sellPriceData1}, y: ${sellVolData1}}`

//buyPriceData[i] = buyPriceData[i].replace(/"/g, "");
//sellPriceData[i] = sellPriceData[i].replace(/"/g, "");
// buyPriceData.push ({ x: buyPriceData1, y: buyVolData1 });
// sellPriceData.push ({ x: sellPriceData1, y: sellVolData1 });
 i++;
}
while ( document.querySelectorAll(".column-date.sorting_1")[i].textContent == selectedDate && i < 9);

}

setInterval(() => {

 
  refreshCurveData();
  myChart.update();
 
  },2500);

};

</script>
```

When I replace the codes in the "data" fields with buyPriceData and sellPriceData respectively, the graph does not visualize, I also tried doing:

```js
 data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Line A',
    
        data: Object.values(buyPriceData)
      },
      {
        label: 'Line B',
    
        data: Object.values(sellPriceData)
      }
      ]
  },
```

But I still have the same problem, please can someone help me with this?

I've created a pen here: https://codepen.io/scottfranc/pen/BaLGwZK

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are saving a String in `buyPriceData`. It looks like it should be an object

Maybe try this:

`buyPriceData[i] = { x: buyPriceData1, y: buyVolData1 };`

and then do the same for `sellPriceData`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I tried this and it also didn't work. :(

Comment: actually, this worked! thank you! I had some other issues with the graph that prevented it from working.